# Modelling gradient lattice

Tags: modeling, lattice

[image: 4-lattice layer; for making a gradient lattice, for instance, I like to add another 4-layer with smaller porosities or windows. The first 4-layer 88 or 99 then the second 4-layer 5*5. The shared image would be the second 4-layer]

I have a 4-layer lattice (.STL file) that I like to edit to a gradient lattice, changing the gaps between lines from low to high or addition of other layers. Could you help me by utilising which tools I can do it? I tried Loop cut, vertex and extrusion so far, although still struggling.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site :) If you'd like, could you add some images showing what you mean by 4-layer (gradient) lattice? Your question might be easier to understand and answered more quickly that way! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, indeed, but how should I add an image?

Answer (score 0):

[4-lattice layer; for making a gradient lattice, for instance, I like to add another 4-layer with smaller porosities or windows. The first 4-layer 8*8 or 9*9 then the second 4-layer 5*5. The shared image would be the second 4-layer]